# RoR "file_field" and Twitter bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to customize this part of code in my Rails3 application

```
<%= f.submit "Create my account", :class => "btn btn-small btn-primary btn-inverse" %>
<%= f.file_field :photo %>
```

into this:

```
<%= f.submit "Create my account", :class => "btn btn-small btn-primary btn-inverse" %>
<%= f.file_field :photo, :class => "btn btn-small btn-primary btn-inverse" %>
```

but the file_field doesnt not seem to respond to customization.

Can somebody help me in this one?

Comment: Check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13731666/316700

Answer (score 3):

I used mindriot's suggestion, but needed to add one comma after the inline onchange js and couldn't edit his answer as one-character edits are not allowed:

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <span class="btn btn-small btn-primary btn-inverse" onclick="$(this).parent().find('input[type=file]').click();">Browse</span>
    <%= f.file_field :file_upload, onchange: "$(this).parent().parent().find('.form-control').html($(this).val().split(/[\\\\|/]/).pop());", style: "display: none;" %>
  </span>
  <span class="form-control"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: It saved a lot of time :) will edit js function for multiple files upload

Answer (score 0):

the class are applied to the input and not the button

http://jsfiddle.net/baptme/k3KtH/

If you want to style the button you can use the method described here :
http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="input-group">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <span class="btn btn-small btn-primary btn-inverse" onclick="$(this).parent().find('input[type=file]').click();">Browse</span>
    <%= f.file_field :photo, onchange: "$(this).parent().parent().find('.form-control').html($(this).val().split(/[\\\\|/]/).pop());" style: "display: none;" %>
  </span>
  <span class="form-control"></span>
</div>
```

Based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30489353/1011746).

Comment: Missing comma on this response Mindriot. 
`" style: "display: none;" %>` should be `", style: "display: none;" %>`