# Asp.net mvc3 bootstrap

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to implement bootstrap css insde of my mvc application.Here is code:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Url.Content("~/Content/bootstrap.min.css")">

@using (Html.BeginForm("Upload","Home",FormMethod.Post,new{enctype="multipart/form-data"}))

{    <input type="file" name="fileUpload" class="btn-file"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" class="btn btn-primary"/>

}
```

But btn-file class doesn't implement to fileupload.Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Twitter Bootstrap Form File Element upload button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235206/twitter-bootstrap-form-file-element-upload-button)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12915459/1178921