# Styling an upload button

Tags: html, css

How do I style the normal upload file button using CSS?

```
<input type="file">
```

I have tried styling using bootstrap classes but it's only the surrounding area around the button that is being styled.

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235206/twitter-bootstrap-form-file-element-upload-button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem and gone through so many example and found this solution try this ..i hope this will help you [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9qKrB/18/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="duplicate">SelectPicture</div><br>
<input id="orginal" type='file'" /><br>
```

**CSS**

```
.duplicate {
    background-color:blue;
    width:100px;
    height:40px;
}
.duplicate:hover{
    background-color:green;
}

#orginal {
 display:none;
}
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.duplicate').bind("click" , function () {
        $('#orginal').click();
    });
});
```

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/572768/styling-an-input-type-file-button)

Comment: This is simple and works better than all those other solutions...thanks