# Issue while creating file upload button using twitter bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using bootstrap controls in my application. I'm trying to create a file upload control in my application.

Here is my code:

```
<input type="file" id="fileUploadTest" runat="server" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        function () {
            $('#fileUploadTest').ace_file_input({
                no_file: 'No File ...',
                btn_choose: 'Choose',
                btn_change: 'Change',
                droppable: false,
                onchange: null,
                thumbnail: false
            });
        }
    );
</script>
```

I'm using

File upload button is not displaying.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/9nwaV/3/)

```
$(document).ready(
                    function () {
                        $('#fileUploadTest').ace_file_input({
                           no_file: 'No File ...',
                            btn_choose: 'Choose',
                            btn_change: 'Change',
                            droppable: false,
                            onchange: null,
                            thumbnail: false
                        });
                    }
                );
```

[Twitter Bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235206/twitter-bootstrap-form-file-element-upload-button)