# Replace django forms.ImageField input button to bootstrap-like button

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-forms, django-models

I'm trying to change the ugly input type="file" to a more stylish bootstrap button. I tried to modify the widget giving him `attrs` of class `btn btn-lg btn-primary` but it gives some weird styling. I appreciate if there's a solution without using `django-crispy-forms`.

```
class CreateProductForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Product

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CreateProductForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['picture'] = forms.ImageField(u'imagen', widget=forms.ClearableFileInput(attrs={'class':'btn btn-lg btn-primary'}))
```

Answer (score 0):

i think the problem is 'class':'btn btn-lg btn-primary'  if you want  stylish bootstrap button you can check[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235206/twitter-bootstrap-form-file-element-upload-button)