# Why does shinyFeedback overwrite custom CSS?

Tags: css, r, shiny

**Goal:**
In my app, the user is supposed to upload a `.csv` file. If a file other than `.csv` is uploaded, a warning message (`showFeedbackWarning()`) should appear around the the `fileInput()` widget. If the user corrects his input and uploads a `.csv` file, the message should disappear again (`hideFeedback()`).
All this already works in the app. But now I would like to change the colour of the progress bar in `fileInput()` to another colour for example red ([like in this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32494765/r-shiny-color-fileinput-button-and-progress-bar)). However, the warning message should still appear in its default colour orange.

**Problem:**
shinyFeedback overwrites my custom CSS and the colour of the progress bar is not changed. I can of course use `!important`, but then the colour of the bar in the warning message also turns red and I don't want this.

Do any of you know how to solve this problem?

**Reprex:**

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyFeedback)


ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),
  fileInput(
    inputId = "upload",
    label = "Upload file:",
    accept = ".csv"
  ),
  tags$style(".progress-bar {
             background-color: red;
             }"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data_in <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$upload$name)

    if (ext == "csv") {
      hideFeedback("upload")
      read.delim(
        input$upload$datapath,
        sep = ";"
      )
    } else {
      showFeedbackWarning(
        inputId = "upload"
      )
    }
  })

  output$text <- renderPrint({
    class(data_in())
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `shinyjs` to change the color dynamically:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyFeedback)

ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyFeedback(),
  useShinyjs(),
  fileInput(
    inputId = "upload",
    label = "Upload file:",
    accept = ".csv"
  ),
  # tags$style(".progress-bar {
  #            background-color: blue; 
  #            }"),
  verbatimTextOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  data_in <- reactive({
    req(input$upload)
    ext <- tools::file_ext(input$upload$name)
    
    if (ext == "csv") {
      hideFeedback("upload")
      runjs('document.querySelector("#upload_progress > div").style.setProperty("background-color", "green", "important");')
      read.delim(
        input$upload$datapath,
        sep = ";"
      )
    } else {
      showFeedbackWarning(
        inputId = "upload",
        color = "red"
      )
    }
  })
  
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    class(data_in())
  })
}


shinyApp(ui, server)
```