# How to make Bootstrap file browse button using django-crispy-forms

Tags: python, html, django, twitter-bootstrap-3, django-crispy-forms

Here is my Django **forms.py** script, using [django-crispy-forms](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from django import forms
from .models import Method1
from crispy_forms.helper import FormHelper
from crispy_forms.layout import Submit, Layout

class Method1Form(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """ Use for wrapping bootstrap
        This is crispy stuff.
        """
        super(Method1Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.form_id = 'id-method1Form'
        self.helper.form_class =  'form-horizontal'
        self.helper.label_class = 'col-lg-2'
        self.helper.field_class = 'col-lg-8'
        self.helper.form_method = 'post'
        self.fields['inputfile_param'].label = "Input File"
        self.fields['species_param'].label = "Species"
        self.fields['norm_mode_param'].label = "Normalization"
        self.fields['logscale_param'].label = "Log Scale"
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
                'inputfile_param',
                'species_param',
                'norm_mode_param',
                'logscale_param',
          )
        self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
```

I can create the following form:

[image]

As shown there, I'd like to make the browse button with Bootstrap style.
How can achieve that?

I'm thinking of something like this:

[image]

Complete **HTML rendered by Django** looks like this:

```css
/* Stuff for django-crispy */
.asteriskField {
        display: none;
}


.form-control {
    font-size:18px;
    font-family:  "Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue;
}

.form-horizontal {
    padding-left: 120px;
    padding-right: 130px;
    font-size:20px;
    font-family:  "Helvetica Neue",HelveticaNeue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
        <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       </head>


<body>
   
    <!--- DISPLAY THE FORM -->
    

<form  id="id-method1Form" class="form-horizontal" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data"> <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='JdUjVaRwOkOxbQmoeSaSHTaDNTlwjs5U' /> <div id="div_id_inputfile_param" class="form-group"> <label for="id_inputfile_param" class="control-label col-lg-2 requiredField">
                Input File<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls col-lg-8"> <input class="clearablefileinput" id="id_inputfile_param" name="inputfile_param" type="file" /> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_species_param" class="form-group"> <label for="id_species_param" class="control-label col-lg-2 requiredField">
                Species<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls col-lg-8"> <select class="select form-control" id="id_species_param" name="species_param">
<option value="mouse" selected="selected">Mouse</option>
<option value="human">Human</option>
</select> </div> </div> <div id="div_id_norm_mode_param" class="form-group"> <label for="id_norm_mode_param" class="control-label col-lg-2 requiredField">
                Normalization<span class="asteriskField">*</span> </label> <div class="controls col-lg-8"> <select class="select form-control" id="id_norm_mode_param" name="norm_mode_param">
<option value="genecount_norm" selected="selected">Gene Count</option>
<option value="totalscore_norm">Total Score</option>
</select> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="controls col-lg-offset-2 col-lg-8"> <div id="div_id_logscale_param" class="checkbox"> <label for="id_logscale_param" class=""> <input class="checkboxinput" id="id_logscale_param" name="logscale_param" type="checkbox" />
                    Log Scale
                    


    




    



                </label> </div> </div> </div> <div class="form-group"> <div class="aab controls col-lg-2"></div> <div class="controls col-lg-8"> <input type="submit"
    name="submit"
    value="Submit"
    
        class="btn btn-primary"
        id="submit-id-submit"
    
    
    /> </div> </div> </form>

    <!--- END FORM DISPLAY-->

    
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235206/twitter-bootstrap-form-file-element-upload-button

Comment: Useful link, but a way built into crispy-forms would be much easier...

Answer (score 2):

For those that find this, the previous answer does NOT work. The OP is asking for a file input field, not any type of field with a button on it. It seems like Crispy doesn't plan on ever fixing this issue (see [issue](https://github.com/django-crispy-forms/django-crispy-forms/issues/734)). Using `FieldWithButtons` will create an input field with the same default button in addition to a crispy button that says "Go", like this: [Go Browse button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OtoG.png)

The only crispy-centric way to do this is by creating a Browse button template and simply calling `template=<your_template>.html` when you make the field. I pulled bits from the BaseInput template to make this and it works.

file_input.html

```
<label for="{% if input.id %}{{ input.id }}{% else %}{{ input.input_type }}-id-{{ input.name|slugify }}{% endif %}" class="btn btn-secondary">
    {% if field.field.required %}<span class="asteriskField">*</span>{% endif %}
    Browse
    <input type="file"
           name="{% if input.name|wordcount > 1 %}{{ input.name|slugify }}{% else %}{{ input.name }}{% endif %}"
           class="{{ input.field_classes }}"
           id="{% if input.id %}{{ input.id }}{% else %}{{ input.input_type }}-id-{{ input.name|slugify }}{% endif %}"
           hidden
           >
</label>
```

forms.py

```
class ProfileUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ['image']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            # Fieldset('', *self.fields),
            Fieldset('', Button('image', "Browse", css_class="clearablefileinput form-control-file", template="file_input.html", css_id="id_image")),
            FormActions(
                Submit('save', 'Update Profile'),
            )
        )
```

views.py

```
def profile(request):
    p_form = ProfileUpdateForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.profile, files=request.FILES)
    #...etc...
```

Result:
[Bootstrappy browse button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDVxn.png)

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but for any one interested, Crispy Forms has this in the documentation:

```
 FieldWithButtons: You can create an input connected with buttons:

 FieldWithButtons('field_name', StrictButton("Go!"))
```

[image]

this is in the docs for crispy forms [Bootstrap Layout objects](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/layouts.html#bootstrap-layout-objects)