# Bootstrap Browse File Button Style

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a question. I have a bootstrap input with type of file:

Html code:

```
input id="fileUpload" class="form-control" name="FileUpload" multiple="" type="file"
```

However it turns out to be that the "browse" button is being cropped. I would like to ask if it is possible or how to change the size of the "browse" button using html or css.

[image]

Comment: post your code so we can see what you've done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<input id="fileUpload" name="FileUpload" multiple="" type="file" />
```

If you would like to keep your fileupload as button please look at this 
[Twitter Bootstrap Form File Element upload button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235206/twitter-bootstrap-form-file-element-upload-button)

Comment: please accept this Answer if it solved your question, so that anyone in help can know the answer