# In Html How do I vertically align label acting as button with button so line up correctly

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4

How do I align label element vertically with button.

I am using this hack to make a file button look like the regular bootstrap buttons

[Twitter Bootstrap Form File Element Upload Button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11235206/twitter-bootstrap-form-file-element-upload-button/18164555#18164555)

The trouble is the button is no longer vertically aligned properly with the the regular buttons. (If I replace the label element with regular button element it looks correct but then of course it does not work.

```
<div style="padding:0.25em">
    <button type="button" title="Select All" name="select_all" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="selectAll(&#x27;ARTWORK_TABLE&#x27;);">
        Select All
    </button>
    <button type="button" title="UnSelect All" name="select_all" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="unselectAll(&#x27;ARTWORK_TABLE&#x27;);">
        UnSelect All
    </button>
    <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary">
        Browse
        <input type="file" id="fileupload" accept="image/*" onchange="uploadImageFile(this.files);" style="display:none">
    </label>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a [margin utility class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/spacing/) (`mt-2`) seems to work..

```
<div class="container">
    <div style="padding:0.25em">
        <button type="button" title="Select All" name="select_all" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="selectAll('ARTWORK_TABLE');">
            Select All
        </button>
        <button type="button" title="UnSelect All" name="select_all" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" onclick="unselectAll('ARTWORK_TABLE');">
            UnSelect All
        </button>
        <label class="btn btn-outline-secondary mt-2">
            Browse
            <input type="file" id="fileupload" accept="image/*" onchange="uploadImageFile(this.files);" style="display:none">
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/kFHG1BDI1E